# How to get a button to play x number of times using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to javascript and I am trying to work backwards to figure out how this works. I found this section of code online that causes a button to play three times before getting disabled:

```
<button onclick='buttonFunction(this)'>Click</button>
<p id="parag">...</p>

  <script> 
    var counter = -1;
    var writing = (function() {
      var myArray = ["one ", "two ", "three!"];
      return function() {
        return myArray[counter += 1];
      }
    });

    function buttonFunction(self) {
      document.getElementById('parag').innerHTML += writing();
      if (counter == 2) {
        self.disabled = true;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

When I run that bit of code, it functions exactly how I expect it to, however, when I try to apply the same logic to this bit of code:

```
  <script>
    function play() {
      var video = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3');
      video.play();

      // disables the button while playing
      var iterations = 0;
      video.addEventListener('play', function () {    
        iterations++;
        const button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.disabled = true;
      }, false);


      video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        // alert(iterations); 
        if (iterations == 1) {
          const button = document.getElementById('button');
          button.disabled = true;
        } else {
          const button = document.getElementById('button');
          button.disabled = false;
        }
      }, false);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <input id="button" class="audioo1" type="button" onclick="play()" value="Play Audio"/>
</body>
```

I understand that the second bit of code isn't completely analogous to the first one, since its a bit more complicated (the button also needs to be turned off while the `audio` is playing. But I am getting lost in the if statement. Anytime I change the value of iterations from 1 to any other number, it simply lets the user press the button forever. Why does the first block of code work but the second does not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to init your var out of scope of your play function.

https://jsfiddle.net/3d0oprbL/

```
<input id="button" class="audioo1" type="button" onclick="play()" value="Play Audio"/>
```

js:

```
var iterations = 0;
   function play() {
     var video = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3');
     video.play();


// disables the button while playing
    video.addEventListener('play', function () {    
        iterations ++;
            const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.disabled = true;
    }, false);


    video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        //alert(iterations); 
        if (iterations == 3) {
            const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.disabled = true;
        }else{
           const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.disabled = false;
        }
    }, false);
    }
```